# What Logo should we use for Ubuntu Power Users?

Tags: 11.04

Please post and vote on your sugestions for the [Ubuntu Power Users](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerUsers/)' logo. This logo must be a [pictogram](http://design.canonical.com/brand/8.%20Pictograms.pdf). The full list of design guidelines is on the Ubuntu Power Users' [Logo Submission](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerUsers/LogoSubmission) page.

Comment: Not sure if this is the appropriate place for this

Comment: FYI: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1016310#1016310

Comment: @ændrük I posted this based on precedent of other ubuntu power user polls being held here. Is there a better place to deal with this type of thing that you know of? The wiki is great, but it doesn't allow for voting, and is harder to post to.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Hammer]

Here is a basic sledge hammer based logo.